# SQL to sort columns within each row and order rows based on this

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, select

What SQL select query can I use to sort each row and then order the sorted rows?

E.g.: *table tab (c1, c2, c3, c4)*

```
2,5,8,4
2,1,6,7
5,2,9,3
```

The query must give:

```
1,2,6,7
2,3,5,9
2,4,5,8
```

Comment: Do it in application layer, not in database.

Comment: @Yosi: Easy to use `ORDER BY`, but I have no clue on how to sort the columns in each row

Comment: @slashmais If the number of columns is fixed (and small), a very complex `CASE` can solve it. There are *only* 24 possible ordering of four columns (4!) :-) :-)

Comment: Maybe you can create some complex query with `CROSS APPLY` but I think that it will be almost impossible. probably you'll need call external programming to do the work.

Comment: @fancyPants: am using sqlite database browser & is hoping it can be done with a query, without having to write an app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
MIN(c1, c2, c3, c4) AS new_c1,
CASE MIN(c1, c2, c3, c4) WHEN c1 THEN MIN(c2, c3, c4)
                         WHEN c2 THEN MIN(c1, c3, c4)
                         WHEN c3 THEN MIN(c1, c2, c4)
                         WHEN c4 THEN MIN(c1, c2, c3)
                         END AS new_c2,
CASE MAX(c1, c2, c3, c4) WHEN c1 THEN MAX(c2, c3, c4)
                         WHEN c2 THEN MAX(c1, c3, c4)
                         WHEN c3 THEN MAX(c1, c2, c4)
                         WHEN c4 THEN MAX(c1, c2, c3)
                         END AS new_c3,
MAX(c1, c2, c3, c4) AS new_c4
FROM tab
ORDER BY new_c1, new_c2, new_c3, new_c4
```

- see it working in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/010dc/2/0)
- see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) for `min()` and `max()` functions

Quote:

> Note that max() [and min()] is a simple function when it has 2 or more arguments but operates as an aggregate function if given only a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's just somthing to start with, maybe not the most "clean" code, but it will work

```
SELECT CASE WHEN C1 < C2 THEN 
                CASE WHEN C1 < C3 THEN C1 ELSE C3 END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN C2 < C3 THEN C2 ELSE C3 END
       END

From YourTable
```

This will select the smallest element in the first place.
Three more of those and you are good to go..
Once you have this result set, you can order by the first column.

Comment: Makes the comparison a little bit more annoying, but it's the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nums2
(
   Row int,
   V int
);

INSERT INTO nums2
SELECT *     
FROM
(
    SELECT rowid Row, c1 V FROM nums
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rowid Row, c2 V FROM nums
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rowid Row, c3 V FROM nums
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rowid Row, c4 V FROM nums
) 
ORDER BY Row, V;

SELECT n1.V v1, n2.V v2, n3.V v3, n4.V v4
    FROM nums2 n1
    INNER JOIN nums2 n2 ON n1.Row = n2.Row AND n2.rowid = n1.rowid + 1
    INNER JOIN nums2 n3 ON n1.Row = n3.Row AND n3.rowid = n1.rowid + 2
    INNER JOIN nums2 n4 ON n1.Row = n4.Row AND n4.rowid = n1.rowid + 3
    WHERE ((n1.rowid - 1) % 4 = 0)
    ORDER BY n1.V, n2.V, n3.V, n4.V
```

It uses a temporary table (`nums2`) where to save the "linearized" rows, and the hidden column `rowid` to then group the rows back.

Tester: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d0232/38

The last select can be simplified a little:

```
SELECT n1.V v1, n2.V v2, n3.V v3, n4.V v4
    FROM nums2 n1
    INNER JOIN nums2 n2 ON n2.rowid = n1.rowid + 1
    INNER JOIN nums2 n3 ON n3.rowid = n1.rowid + 2
    INNER JOIN nums2 n4 ON n4.rowid = n1.rowid + 3
    WHERE ((n1.rowid - 1) % 4 = 0)
    ORDER BY n1.V, n2.V, n3.V, n4.V
```

because the `WHERE` expression will "select" the lowest value of each row.

Tester: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d0232/39

The queries are easily expandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot the table to `(row_nr, col_nr, value)` format.  Then you can sort it, and unpivot it back to `(row_nr, val1, val2, val3, val4)` format.

```
; with  with_numbers as 
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by c1) rn
        ,       *
        from    tab
        )
,       normalized(rn, nr) as 
        (
        select  rn, c1 from with_numbers
        union all
        select  rn, c2 from with_numbers
        union all
        select  rn, c3 from with_numbers
        union all
        select  rn, c4 from with_numbers
        )
,       normalized_with_number as
        (
        select  row_number() over (partition by rn order by nr) rn2
        ,       *
        from    normalized
        )
,       sorted as
        (
        select  max(case when rn2 = 1 then nr end) c1
        ,       max(case when rn2 = 2 then nr end) c2
        ,       max(case when rn2 = 3 then nr end) c3
        ,       max(case when rn2 = 4 then nr end) c4
        from    normalized_with_number
        group by
                rn      
        )
select  *
from    sorted
order by
        c1
,       c2
,       c3
,       c4
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/010dc/1/0)

Comment: He had asked for SQLite, so no CTE and no `row_number` :-) :-)

Comment: @xanatos: haha... drat.  And I thought I was being clever :D